# UITableView setter method functions not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, data-management

functions like this one:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    NSLog(@"called")
    return 1;
}
```

aren't being called, because the log doesn't appear at the console. I tried using

```
[table realoadData]
```

but it still doesn't work

Comment: Is the table view's `dataSource` set?

Comment: Yes, it is set to 'self'

Comment: Can you include the code in which you're both setting the datasource and calling reload?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you have both the UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate set to the class that this method is located in

```
.h 
@interface class_name : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{ UITableView *tableView; }

.m
in the viewDidLoad (or any other loading method)

tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
```

If you are subclassing UITableViewController, it should be working already

hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

1. In Nib file, you need to outlet tableview.
2. Your subclass must have UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate.
3. Assign tableview.delegate = self and tableView.dataSource = self;